# Need a reverse effect for hiding div

Tags: jquery

my full script is running but when i will click on div then div will hide with reverse effect

here is my code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.lnkcss 
{
    margin-left:350px;
}

.BusyStyles
    {
        background-image: url('http://www.bba-reman.com/images/ajax-loader.gif');
        background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; 
    }

 #transition {

display:none;
position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; z-index:50;
border:1px solid #666;
width:100px; height:100px;
filter:alpha(opacity=0.2);
-moz-opacity:0.2;
-khtml-opacity: 0.2;
opacity: 0.2;
}

</style>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#lnk').click(function (e) {
            $('body').append('<div id="transition"></div>').show();

            var $t = $('#transition'),
            to = $(this).offset(),
            td = $(document);

            $t.css({
                top: to.top + 50,
                left: to.left + 50,
                display: 'block'
            }).animate({
                opacity: 1,
                top: td.height() / 2,
                left: td.width() / 2
            }, 600, function () {
                $(this).animate({
                    top: '-=75',
                    left: '-=50'
                }, 600);

                $('#transition').addClass("BusyStyles");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#transition').animate({
                        top: (td.height() / 2) - 200/2,
                        left: (td.width() / 2) - 250/2,
                        width: 250,
                        height: 200
                    }, 600, function () {
                        //alert('pp');
                        // to do things   
                        $('#transition').removeClass("BusyStyles");
                        $('#transition').html('<b>Welcome...</b>');
                    });
                }, 3000);
            });

            $t.click(function (e) {
                //alert('pp');
                $(this).fadeOut('slow').remove();
            });
            return false;
        });


    });
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<a href="#" id='lnk' class="lnkcss">FeedBack</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

what code i need to add to get a reverse effect. 
when i will click on transition div then transition div gradually transparent 
and squeeze in size and move towards feedback link and at last hide. 
if possible please guide me.

here is my code link. 
http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/kPZrZ/2/

thanks

Comment: What issue are you having with reversing it?  You wrote the code to animate it in, changing that to animate out should be trivial.

Comment: one major things that the above script not working same way in IE 8. please run the script in IE and u will look the difference. so what will be good fix for IE. when i run this in IE then a flicker occur but in case of other browser no flicker occur. thanks.

Comment: It pretty much looks the same in IE 8 for me.  What are you seeing that is different?  IE8 is always tricky because it still lacks support for certain CSS features.

Comment: john when u feel it is very easy to create a reverse effect then why don't u guide me. here is demo url http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/kPZrZ/2/ please have look & guide me. thanks